# facing issue with log4j2 : java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: struts2, log4j2

I'm facing issue with log4j2

below is my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.opensymphony.xwork2" level="info"/>
        <Logger name="org.apache.struts2" level="info"/>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

below is the exception

```
<Jun 21, 2018 7:23:48 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.createContextData(Log4jLogEvent.java:472)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.<init>(Log4jLogEvent.java:331)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.DefaultLogEventFactory.createEvent(DefaultLogEventFactory.java:54)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:401)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Initial capacity must be at least one but was 0
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.SortedArrayStringMap.<init>(SortedArrayStringMap.java:102)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataFactory.createContextData(ContextDataFactory.java:109)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ContextDataFactory.<clinit>(ContextDataFactory.java:57)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.createContextData(Log4jLogEvent.java:472)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.<init>(Log4jLogEvent.java:331)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

above exception resulting to failure of war file deployment.

below are the jars used

```
1.commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar
2.commons-io-2.5.jar
3.commons-lang3-3.6.jar
4.commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
5.freemarker-2.3.26-incubating.jar
6.javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
7.log4j-1.2-api-2.11.0.jar
8.log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
9.log4j-core-2.11.0.jar
10.ognl-3.1.15.jar
11.struts2-core-2.5.16.jar
```

what do i need to correct?

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading log4j-api-2.10.0.jar to 2.11.0.

`IllegalArgumentException` is thrown from the constructor of `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.SortedArrayStringMap`:

```
public SortedArrayStringMap(final int initialCapacity) {
    if (initialCapacity < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Initial capacity must be at least one but was " + initialCapacity);
    }
    threshold = ceilingNextPowerOfTwo(initialCapacity);
}
```

and the given parameter `initialCapacity` has been changed since 2.11 as follows:

https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/log4j-2.10.0/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/ContextDataFactory.java#L54

https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/log4j-2.11.0/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/ContextDataFactory.java#L57

Comment: This answer is close, but i think is backwards, 2.10 is has the initialCapacity of 1 where 2.11 is 0, going to 2.10 fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, I was using 2.11.0 and facing same issue. moving on 2.10.0 version, fixed issue for me. Thank you.

Comment: 2.11.2 has the same problem.

Comment: I was using older log4j-api (2.9.1) with newer log4j-core (2.11.2) which caused this issue. Updating log4j-api to 2.11.2 solved the issue for me.

Comment: The newer log4j-api throws exception if value < 0 but older throws if value < 1 and newer log4j-core initializes with 0 while older log4j-core initializes with 1

Answer (score 0):

Updating the log4j-api and log4j-core from 2.11.1 to 2.12.0 solved the same problem for me.